# Batch creating partition then partition node; access failing

Tags: devices, block-device, scsi

So I've got an program that takes a device, partitions it and then creates the device node for the partition. The problem is, that the kernel does not pick up the device until some kind of rescan is forced. For ex.:

- Partition device
- Make node
- cat node > cat: /dev/xxx: No such device or address

But this works:

- Partition device
- Make node
- Run cfdisk /dev/xxx and exit instantly
- cat node > Works fine

Why is this? Is there some kind of ioctl to re scan the SCSI bus or something?

And, this does not work:

```
echo "- - -" > /sys/class/scsi_host/hostX/scan
```

Comment: How are you partitioning the disk in the first place?

Comment: libparted. I figured it out. libparted has 2 calls to write info to disk. One is to commit to disk, the other is to commit to the kernel. I forgot the second one. More specifically, it is the called ped_disk_commit_to_os()

Comment: Yeah, the "commit to kernel" is the important part.  Tools like `fdisk` will do this automatically.  NOTE that if the disk is in use (eg the disk holding the root partition) then the kernel won't necessarily pick up the change.

Comment: Yup that was it. I'm partitioning external SCSI drives, so no worries.

Answer (score 1):

Use `partprobe /dev/xxx`

`partprobe` is part of the `parted` package.  From the man page:

> `partprobe` is a program that informs the operating system kernel of partition table changes`

Another alternative if you have a partitioned block device (e.g. a disk image file) and you want to automatically create device nodes (e.g. /dev/loop*) for it AND inform the kernel, you can use `kpartx`.  It's called automatically on hotplug events like inserting a USB or hot-swap SATA drive.

Comment: `partprobe` does nothing, except call `ped_commit_to_os()` for all SCSI drives. Look at the source code of `partprobe`. That is how I figured it out and implemented it.

Comment: in other words, it does what i said it does (and it only probes ALL drives if you don't give it any device args).  If you want to know about specific programming language function calls rather than unix/linux command-line tools, you should mention that fact (as well as the language you're writing in).